# Создание бекапов конфликтных файлов при мерже

Tags: git, резервное-копирование, git-merge

Есть такая проблема, что при мерже двух веток у меня создается много конфлитов, которые я решаю вручную. И бывает такой случай, что я разрешил какой-то из конфликтов в каком-то файле неправильно. Правильность разрешённого конфликта я могу проверить только когда разрешу их все. В git есть какое-нибудь легкое решение этой проблемы? Мне в голову лишь приходит идея о том, чтобы сканировать все файлы и искать в них метки конфликтов, но файлов в проекте много, поэтому мне бы хотя бы получить список конфликтных файлов из гита, но я не знаю как. И после получения этих файлов уже делать бекап

Comment: вы решаете не ту задачу. Надо сводить количество конфликтов к 0, а не решать их вручную, делая бэкапы.

Comment: @Эникейщик Увы, в сфере геймдева, на unity, и в немалой команде программистов сложно свести кол-во конфликтов к 0

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/501407/4827341